# Is python site manual totally generated by pydoc?

Tags: python, pydoc

I tried pydoc to some internal package but the output html is far different from the site version. So I wondered how to generate the doc just like the site document. Or there has to be done by manually tweak and edit

thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the python site doc is generated using Sphinx 
[Look here](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)

You can see the line 'Created using Sphinx 1.0.7. ' written at end of http://docs.python.org/index.html page

Answer (score 1):

Yes python doc is created from sphinx you can check the "Project Using Sphinx" https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/examples.html.